# Writing files to the system in my GWT - Google App Engine (GAE) application

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, file-io, hosting

I have created a GWT application and now want to deploy it outside GAE. The reason I wish to deploy outside the GAE is the [Sandbox](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) security feature of GAE, which disallows me from writing files to my system. I store my data in the form of an ontology (.[owl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language) file) under my '/war/WEB_INF' and I want the end user to be able to modify (write to / save) this file through the server.

I understand that GAE does not let me do this, but is there a paid Google Service (e.g. google apps) that would allow hosting a GWT application which would allow writing files to the system? For instance, like an add-on to GAE?

If not, what solution would you recommend to host a GWT application (that would let me write a file to the WEB-INF folder) on the web?

**EDIT:** I solved this by deploying the GWT project as a .war file and hosting in TomCat.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very new to GAE, but in case you haven't looked at their experimental write/read blobstore services you can check that out [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore). They have a similar API for python I believe. It's ofcourse stored on the GAE blobstore and not under /war/WEB-INF/ directory but It does allow a possible solution to what you're looking for.

Also, if you're looking to run your own server (possibly on EC2 for example), then you might want to look into [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/). But I, personally, would stay away from that as a solution because I highly doubt that AppScale performs as well as google's GAE web servers and furthermore lacks the same degree of support/development.

Comment: I actually use blobstore Java API to store files in the database. You can make a basic servlet mapped to something like /fileServlet/* and then call it with path and filenames which you can parse to identify a certain blob (which previously ofcourse you saved with some associated "path" and "file name") and it will act just like your own fileSystem.

Comment: Hmm, so I actually do not even have to store the data (my ontology) under WEB-INF at all?  Security-wise, would using the blobstore be less credible than stroring the ontology under my file system?

Comment: Well, I am not sure this lets modifying or overwriting a file : 'Blobs can't be modified after they're created, although they can be deleted.' Also, my ontology is greater than 32mb's but apparently:
"An app can read a Blobstore value a portion at a time using an API call. The size of the portion can be up to the maximum size of an API return value."

Comment: I think that statement is not intended for the experimental blobstore read/write API. The example shows that you can write more to the same file after retrieving it using: new AppEngineFile(path). And as for the size limitation, I think you can request the file in chunks. But there are very real limitations in GAE that you'll have to deal with.

Comment: Writing to the blobstore is _more_ secure than writing to the filesystem, because a bug can't cause you to let the user write arbitrary data to your FS. It's also more scalable, since it works in a distributed architecture like App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ruled out something like creating an `Owl` Entity to hold your ontologies, and arranging for `*.owl` requests to be handled by using that as a key name to find and serve the corresponding `Owl`? That's really simple code.

Comment: Hello David, Thanks a lot for your response. This is something I am not aware of. Could you elaborate / give links? I am a newbie in web applcaitions. Currently, I keep my ontology on the server side (/war/WEB-INF/). Where would I be keeping it in this framework?

Comment: Most of what you need is here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Comment: Hello David, I have read this but it concludes by saying that the maximum allowable 'entity' size is 1 MB, whereas my ontology is a couple of hundred MB's. Did you mean, just store my ontology's url (kept online elsewhere) as a property of an owl entity and then return that url for writing to my ontology? Because, I think storing my actual ontology as a datastore entity is not possible.

Comment: 100s of MBs are going to be a challenge. I retract the datastore suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is primarily a client side technology.  GAE is a server side technology.  You seem to be getting GWT and GAE engine mixed up with each other.  GAE can work with almost any client side technology, and GWT can connect to many different back end platforms.

Are you trying to move your back end code directly to a new platform?  Are you planning on rewriting the back end for a new platform, but keep the GWT code?  What is your goal for this application?  To be used by you and a few friends, or by thousands of people? For free or paying customers?

If you want to move off of AppEngine, you can switch to pretty much any java hosting service that you want - anything from a tiny shared VPS up to a Amazon EC2 mini cloud of your own.  I don't think google offers generic java hosting.  I don't know how you have built your application's back end, but you probably used servlets, which you should be able to get working pretty much anywhere.

If you want to stay on AppEngine, you should think about whether or not you can break your owl file into smaller sections that can be stored as entities in the database.

Whichever platform you choose, if you are planning on serving more than a few people, you will need some way to prevent one giant owl file from becoming a huge bottleneck.

Comment: Hello Peter, Thanks a lot for your response.  My application is a research project and is intended for less then 50 people. It is purely in GWT and I just use GWT RPC to transfer serialisable objects between the client and the server side. I would ideally like to stcik to GAE since deploying applications to GAE through the Eclipse GWT Plugin is so easy. However, the problem is as I said not being able to write a file to my WEB-INF folder. I guess the ideal thing for me to do would be to package my application (.war) and then host it on a java-hosting service?